# Encrypting sections of web config before sending to TFS(or GItHub), and allowing others to decrypt when they pull the code

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, tfs, rsa

I am trying to encrypt a section of my .net web config. I am able to encrypt it by way of command line, and it works on my local machine, with my local machine key. But when I put it on TFS, and someone else pulls it down on another computer, their machine can not decrypt the section that I encrypted on my machine. 
Is there a way to post a public key with your web.config when you post it, or even have it run a .Bat file and decrypt upon building your project?

Comment: `I am able to encrypt it by way of command line` We're not fortune tellers so we can't know how you're encripting your file and thus we can't help you on how to decrypt it... read this on how to post a good question on S.O.: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You could use Git .gitattributes with filters:https://snikt.net/blog/2013/07/04/git-with-transparent-encryption/

Comment: I am simply asking if there is a standard way to encrypt a web config section that can then be placed in a repository such as TFS or Github, Once the code is in the repository and someone pulls the code from the repository they need to be able to decrypt the web config on their machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Pkcs12ProtectedConfigurationProvider` to encrypt your sections. 
It's certificate backed, which you can share via a PFX file. You will have to have the certificate installed in the local machine's cert store for the provider to work.

[Encrypt Web.Config sections](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Encrypt-Configuration-5a8e8dfe)